# Take drone on a plane in Europe?

Tags: regulations, under-250-grams, transportation

I want to take my small (<250 grams) drone on a plane in Europe? Are there any rules regarding this? Should the drone go in carry-on luggage or in the hold?

Comment: I really don't think we should entertain legal questions. First, they are very much akin to purchase recommendation questions, for the reason no matter where you go, the laws will be different. Second, laws change all the time. Thirdly, most of us are not lawyers ... we should not be handing out legal advice. This is just bad juju. Not to mention, this question is very broad.

Comment: To the contrary, this question was raised during the startup phase and there was a strong consensus that regulation questions are within scope and even desirable. https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29983/should-questions-about-legality-be-on-topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not a legal expert by any means, so I just want to say that disclaimer.

As far as I am aware, you can check in the drone itself, but due to their volatile nature, most airlines will require you to carry LiPos in your carry-on luggage so you can react quickly in case the worst happens.

As always, check with your specific airline and the laws specific to your country of origin and your destination.